# XSL - rounding/format-number problem

Tags: xml, xslt, formatting, numbers, rounding

I'm trying to get the value of a number to 2 dec places from my xml.

XML:`<Quantity>0.0050</Quantity>`

XSL:`<xsl:value-of select="format-number($quantity, '####0.00')" />`

However XSL seems to have a problem with this value and outputs `0.00` in one area of the page and `0.01` in the other. Of course in this situation it is favourable to have `0.01`  output in all areas.

Another area has the value `4.221` yet the XSL is outputting `4.23`.

I do realise that `format-number` as a method converts a number to a string.

Not sure how to fix this.

---

**EDIT:**

Ok after a bit of mucking around i found that this works:

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number( round(100*$quantity) div 100 ,"##0.00" )' />
```

Via this [website](http://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200601/msg00664.html)

As this guy mentions XSL uses 'bankers rounding' to round to even numbers instead of the bigger ones.

The solution hardly seems elegant, and means adding a ton of extra functions to an already bulky and complicated XSL file. Surely i'm missing something?

Comment: the inconsistent behavior you are describing is odd. Please post your stylesheet.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not sure why format would be  so inconsistent but from memory the spec for it is...complex.

Meantime, you can use the `round` function ([ref](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_round.html)). Which is less than perfect, but is functional. If you need to have a particular number of sig figs you can use **THE POWER OF MATHS!** and do something like:

`<xsl:value-of select="round(yournum*100) div 100"/>`

Comment: Thanks for this! I had just come across the same method as posted above. It works but it just means routing through the whole stylesheet and changing everything to suit this. Yuk!

Comment: I don't think this approach will work for all cases in XSLT 1.0 because of floating-point errors (please see my answer below for more detail).

Answer (score 18):

I've had endless trouble with decimals in XSLT/XPath 1.0, often a combination of it representing decimals as floating-point numbers and it using half-even rounding (banker's rounding). Unfortunately, the `round(yournum*100) div 100` approach didn't work for me, due to floating-point imprecision. For example, multiplying 1.255 by 100 gives 125.49999999999999 (this isn't meant to be implementation dependent, as it's supposed to be IEEE 754, but I don't know if all implementations do adhere to that). When rounded, this then gives 125, rather than the desired 126.

I've taken the following approach, which I think works (although this is always a tricky area so I won't declare too much confidence!). However, it depends on your XSLT engine supporting EXSLT extensions. It presumes you want to round to two decimal places.

```
<func:function name="local:RoundHalfUp">
    <xsl:param name="number"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($number, '.')">
            <xsl:variable name="decimal" select="estr:split($number, '.')[2]"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($decimal) &gt; 2">
                    <func:result select="format-number(concat($number, '1'), '0.00')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <func:result select="format-number($number, '0.00')"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <func:result select="format-number($number, '0.00')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</func:function>
```

which can be called like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="local:RoundHalfUp(1.255)"/>
```

The namespaces are:

```
xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
xmlns:estr="http://exslt.org/strings"
xmlns:local="http://www.acme.org/local_function"
```

It's important to note that the function *appends* a '1', not adds 0.001 or similar.

Definately better to use XSLT 2.0 if it's an option (because it has a proper decimal type), but I know that's often not an option (from painful experience!).

Comment: When working with floating point, it pays to add a value slightly larger than the largest algorithm error to bias the result to giving values that are more easily trimmed. For example, adding `0.0000001` to the `1.255` would ensure that it would be `125.5000001`, or even `125.501`, which properly rounds to `126`. This is why when comparing two floating point numbers, it is better to subtract them and if the result is less than a number slightly larger than the calculation error, they can be considered equal.

Comment: Hi @Patanjali. Please note the comment in the answer about appending 1 rather than adding a fixed amount. The algorithm doesn't add a fixed amount, which I think avoids the issue you mention, if I have understood you correctly?

Comment: Giles. Sorry, I missed that. It does work for simple rounding, and so answers the OP's question. However, the general approach to dealing with floating point numbers is to cater for the `epsilon` value of the floating point algorithm, and so minimise the risk of falling prey to false negative equality tests. It also facilitates determining the likely error resulting from complex calculations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Answer (score 0):

Compared to all above answers i found

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(xs:decimal($quantity), '####0.00')" />
```

is useful, it is not truncating any decimal point values. truncating exactly specified numbers. if number is in Exponential format we can use as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(xs:decimal(number($quantity)), '####0.00')" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered the issue whereby if you did
    round($number * 100) div 100
you get a floating point representation of .4999999 and the rounding doesn't work properly.

To get around this, This seems to work:
    round($number * 1000 div 10) div 100