# XSL rounding issue

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have an XSL style sheet and I’m using `format-number(xpath,"#,##0")` to round the value. On my local machine the value 1006.5 gets rounded to 1007. However, the same style sheet on the server rounds 1006.5 to 1006.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 1.0 the rounding rules for format-number() are under-specified. (In fact they are defined by reference to the JDK 1.1 specification, which is very hard to find nowadays, but I remember well that it was very underspecified).

Therefore, different XSLT 1.0 processors may behave differently.

XSLT 2.0 defines the rounding rules (though I forget exactly what they are).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be due to different XSLT 1.0 processors using different rounding methods (half-up vs round-to-even/banker's rounding). It might also be due to differences in the way floating point numbers are represented on different machines.

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805248/xsl-rounding-format-number-problem/14853343#14853343) may provide more details and start you off on a solution (the solution there is for rounding to two decimal places, but perhaps you can see how it could be more generally applied).