# How to add two xml tag values using a for:each in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, sum

I want to add up the values in this input XML at COMS level for every CDS/CD node. The output i am expecting is as below.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <CDS>
            <CD>
                   <COMS>
                          <COMP>
                            <VAL>1.220</VAL>
                         </COMP>
                         <COMP>
                            <VAL>2.220</VAL>
                         </COMP>
                   </COMS>

            </CD>
   </CDS>
   <CDS>
            <CD>
                   <COMS>
                          <COMP>
                            <VAL>5.2</VAL>
                         </COMP>
                         <COMP>
                            <VAL>6.5</VAL>
                         </COMP>
                   </COMS>

            </CD>
    </CDS>
    <CDS>
            <CD>
                   <COMS>
                          <COMP>
                            <VAL>4.2</VAL>
                         </COMP>
                         <COMP>
                            <VAL>5.8</VAL>
                         </COMP>
                   </COMS>

            </CD>
    </CDS>
```

Output XML:

```
    <CDS>
           <CD>
                   <COMS>
                            <COMP>
                                    <SUM_VALUE>3.44</SUM_VALUE>
                            </COMP>
                   </COMS>
          </CD>
           <CD>
                   <COMS>
                            <COMP>
                                   <SUM_VALUE>11.7</SUM_VALUE>
                            </COMP>
                  </COMS>
          </CD>
           <CD>
                   <COMS>
                              <COMP>
                                    <SUM_VALUE>10</SUM_VALUE>
                             </COMP>
                   </COMS>
          </CD>
  </CDS>
```

My XSLT code only tries to sum all the values and gives the final output. It would be helpful if someone can explain how to sum the xml values in the for:each loop for the respective comp levels.

Comment: Please post your XSLT code and fix your input so that it is well-formed (currently it has no root element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a **well-formed input**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <CDS>
    <CD>
      <COMS>
        <COMP>
          <VAL>1.220</VAL>
        </COMP>
        <COMP>
          <VAL>2.220</VAL>
        </COMP>
      </COMS>
    </CD>
  </CDS>
  <CDS>
    <CD>
      <COMS>
        <COMP>
          <VAL>5.2</VAL>
        </COMP>
        <COMP>
          <VAL>6.5</VAL>
        </COMP>
      </COMS>
    </CD>
  </CDS>
  <CDS>
    <CD>
      <COMS>
        <COMP>
          <VAL>4.2</VAL>
        </COMP>
        <COMP>
          <VAL>5.8</VAL>
        </COMP>
      </COMS>
    </CD>
  </CDS>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <CDS>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/CDS/CD">
            <CD>
                <COMS>
                    <COMP>
                        <SUM_VALUE><xsl:value-of select="sum(COMS/COMP/VAL)" /></SUM_VALUE>
                    </COMP>
                </COMS>
            </CD>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </CDS>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CDS>
  <CD>
    <COMS>
      <COMP>
        <SUM_VALUE>3.44</SUM_VALUE>
      </COMP>
    </COMS>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <COMS>
      <COMP>
        <SUM_VALUE>11.7</SUM_VALUE>
      </COMP>
    </COMS>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <COMS>
      <COMP>
        <SUM_VALUE>10</SUM_VALUE>
      </COMP>
    </COMS>
  </CD>
</CDS>
```

---

**Note:**

A Java-based engine such as Saxon or Xalan may return `3.4400000000000004` as the sum of 1.22 + 2.22.

Comment: The precision problem could be handled by using XSLT 2.0, or - if this isn't an option - using `format-number()`. But that can be tricky. More info see [StackOverflow - XSL - rounding/format-number problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805248/xsl-rounding-format-number-problem)

Comment: @codefan "*The precision problem could be handled by using XSLT 2.0*" How so?

Comment: See my answer with solution with XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a root element named `root`. Please try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="COMS">
        <xsl:copy>
            <COMP>
                <SUM_VALUE><xsl:value-of select="sum(descendant::VAL)"/></SUM_VALUE>
            </COMP>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CDS">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <CDS>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </CDS>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution without precision problem - example with XSLT 2.0**

If the number precision problem mentioned by @michael.hor257k can't be tolerated, you have the option to do some processing with `format-number()` what not always will lead to a satisfying result.

If XSLT 2.0 is an option, you may use the `xs:decimal` data type.

**EDIT**

Here is the full solution for summing up **all** the `<VAL/>` children of a `<COMP/>` element - regardless how many are found - as requested by commentator @michael.hor257k.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <CDS>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/CDS/CD">
                <CD>
                    <COMS>
                        <COMP>
                            <SUM_VALUE><xsl:apply-templates select="*/COMP[1]" /></SUM_VALUE>
                        </COMP>
                    </COMS>
                </CD>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </CDS>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="COMP">
        <xsl:param name="sum" select="0" />

        <xsl:variable name="newsum">
            <xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal(VAL) + xs:decimal($sum)"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$newsum" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$newsum"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Such solutions need a XSLT 2.0-aware XSLT processor, like Saxon 9.5.

More info, especially on XSLT 1.0 approaches, see: [StackOverflow - XSL - rounding/format-number problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805248/xsl-rounding-format-number-problem)

Comment: "*access the values one-by-one*" It seems to me the cure is worse than the disease...

Comment: I believe rounding/formatting to the nearest cent (or mill, if that's the required precision) should be quite sufficient *in this case*. -- I would not take the given example to imply that the number of summands is always 2 - and the alternative of a named recursive template to do a simple addition is very unappealing. -- P.S. Who is Hugh?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Hugh? I wrote also: this can be solved by a recursive template. But that's beyond the OP's question. The OP didn't respond to your well-done request for more information. All we have, is a broken XML with exact two <COMP/> elements per <COMS/>.... My comment was meant as an additional hint for people coming around and wondering about your words regarding the precision problem. By the way, I really appreciate your short and clean solution. In fact, it was my up-vote you got this morning :-)

Comment: @michael.hor257k Nevertheless, I got your point and will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Added the complete XSLT 2.0 example. Hope, you like it better...