# How can I trim a decimal value to four places behind the decimal point using XSLT

Tags: xslt, trim, bpel

In my ORACLE SOA BPEL process, we are receiving a value as string @ 10.2345678956 but for target system we just need to send upto 4 places in decimal like 10.2345. Could you please tell me how we can achieve that using xslt.

also if source system send value as 10 even those in that case, to target system we need to send 10.0000(always 4 digit in decimal)

Comment: This looks a lot like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805248/xsl-rounding-format-number-problem . Can you please confirm?

Comment: @fvu - thanks for your response. I am not exactly sure if both are same question but I guess we both are trying to achive almost same stuff. as that post give solution as "<xsl:value-of select='format-number( round(100*$quantity) div 100 ,"##0.00" )' />" .. could you please tell me what exactly ##0.00 does here

Comment: 0 represents a position that must be rendered, # a position that will be rendered if significant. Thus, `#0.0000` should be quite close to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which version of XSLT you are using, but in XSLT 1.0 you should do this "by hand", like as follows:

> Note: as Michael says in the comments, you can use format-number in XSLT 1.0. However, the chosen rounding is unclear. While this works, see Michael's answer for a more trivial solution.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="input" select="10.23456789" />

    <xsl:call-template name="truncate">
        <xsl:with-param name="val" select="$input" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="truncate">
    <xsl:param name="val" />
    <xsl:variable name="adj">
        <xsl:value-of select="$val"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($val, '.'))">.</xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>0000</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="before" select="substring-before($adj, '.')" />
    <xsl:variable name="after" select="substring-after($adj, '.')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$before" />
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($after, 1, 4)" />        
</xsl:template>
```

And in XSLT 2.0 and 3.0, you can simply do as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($input, '#.0000')" />
```

But this will round up (halves to even), i.e. with your input it would give you `10.2346`. If that is undesirable, you could use the trick [suggested by fvu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187907/trim-a-decimal-value-to-4-places-using-xslt/32216717#comment52261854_32187907):

```
<xsl:value-of select="
    format-number(xs:integer(number($input) * 10000) div 10000, '#.0000')" />
```

Both the XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0/3.0 versions above will append the necessary zeroes up to four.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `format-number()` in XSLT 1.0 too? -- P.S. `format-number()` does not (always) round up - it rounds to even (in XSLT 2.0, and in some implementations of XSLT 1.0).

Comment: @michael.hor257k: lol, no idea why, but I have been so long with 2.0+, that I just assumed it wouldn't support the function, without checking. You are absolutely right, there's nothing that prevents it. Yes, it rounds to even, I was unclear (the input given rounds up).

Comment: @Abel I have this logic in place <xsl:value-of select="
    format-number(($input), '0.0000000')" />.

How do I trim 0.31661129 to become 0.3166112? Currently it rounds off to 0.3166113

Answer (score 0):

To truncate (i.e. round *down*) a number to 4 decimal digits precision, you can do:

```
floor($number * 10000) div 10000
```

To format the result to always display 4 decimal digits:

```
format-number(floor($number * 10000) div 10000, '0.0000')
```

This works in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 alike.

---

If you don't care about the direction of rounding, then do simply:

```
format-number($number, '0.0000')
```

and be done with it.

Comment: Hi All - Need your input on this thread. The logic shared above is working perfectly fine till date but today when we send a value 5.56 - code break. for value 5.56, as a output it should come as 5.5600 but for some reason its coming as 5.5599

Comment: this is the logic I am trying - format-number((floor(((KBETR div KPEIN) * 10000.0)) div 10000.0),"0.0000")   . Its very strange for me. If I try 6.56 the its working perfectly fine.

Comment: @kumarb We need a reproducible example. My guess is that the value is not exactly 5.56. We'll know for sure if you give us the values of KBETR and KPEIN.

Comment: @michael.hor257k would `format-number($number - 0.00005, '0.0000')` have the same result as `format-number(floor($number * 10000) div 10000, '0.0000')`?

Comment: @dave I think not: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBGD