# Are there any round-to-even function in xslt？or I will do it myself

Tags: xslt-1.0

I will format the integer value with "round-to-even" rounding. Dose it have any function in xslt or I will do myself

```
<Characteristics id="4639" Value="109.912"/>
```

it will display "109.91"

Comment: <CharacteristicsOutput mandateValue="109.912"/>

Comment: According to this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805248/xsl-rounding-format-number-problem XLS's `format-number` function rounds to even. I could not find a specification for this with a quick search, though. It seems that one should better not rely on this (see the discussion on the website referenced there).

Comment: `109.912` is not "integer value" and it's also not a good example for "round-to-even" rounding. Anyway, the answer may depend on the processor you're using. In some XSLT 1.0  processors (e.g. Xalan, Saxon) the `format-number()` function does   "round-to-even" rounding. In others (e.g. libxslt, Microsoft) the implementation is different.